# Android playing external MP3: error -- MediaPlayer start called in state 1

Tags: java, android, mp3, runtime-error, android-mediaplayer

I'm having trouble playing an external MP3 file on Android. I'm using the following code:

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
try {
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new java.net.URL(url).openStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/forvo_temp.mp3");
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,1024);
    byte [] data = new byte[1024];

    int x=0;
    while((x=bis.read(data,0,1024))>=0){
        bos.write(data,0,x);               
    }
    player.reset();
    player.start();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`url` is the string where the external file is. I do have write permission for the SD card (`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`).

On the debug, I see:

```
E MediaPlayer start called in state 1
E MediaPlayer error (-38, 0)
E MediaPlayer Error (-38,0)
```

What might the problem be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer: before calling `player.start()`, you have to run `setDataSource()` and `prepare()`, according to the [State Diagram of the MediaPlayer reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram).

Like this:

```
// Use same path as before
player.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/forvo_temp.mp3");
player.prepare();
```

Comment: @Ohh if you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. You can provide the link to the new question here for reference.

Answer (score -4):

You need to set `AndroidManifest.xml` permission as:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: This is not an answer; I stated in the question that I did this already.